# WCF Service communication using MonoTouch

Tags: wcf, ipad, xamarin.ios

Can anyone point me in the right direction for where to start when calling a WCF Service from Monotouch?

I am developing an IPad App using Monotouch and its data needs to be provided by a WCF Service

Paul

Comment: maybe this can help you http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Introduction_to_Web_Services#Consuming_WCF_Services

Answer (score 1):

As igor said in his comment, try http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Introduction_to_Web_Services#Consuming_WCF_Services for a really good introduction.

Also, this video may help http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV76V_LVqpM

And there are also articles available on how to do cross platform wcf clients - eg http://sim4all.com/blogging/?p=173